# Erro com insert na List do C#

Tags: c#

Estou recebendo um erro quando tento inserir um objeto na lista no msm índice que o id do objeto.

(Erro abaixo do codigo)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many employees will be registered?");
            int qt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            List<Employees> EmployeeList = new List<Employees>();

            for (int i = 0; i < qt; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee: ");
                Console.Write("Id: ");
                int id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee: ");
                Console.Write("Name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee: ");
                Console.Write("Salary: ");
                double salary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Employees Employee = new Employees(id, name, salary);

                EmployeeList.Insert(id, Employee);

            }
            Console.Write("Enter the employee id that will have salary increase: ");
            int idToIncreaseSalary = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter the percentage: ");
            double percentageToIncreaseSalary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            EmployeeList.Find(x => x.Id == idToIncreaseSalary);
            EmployeeList[idToIncreaseSalary].Salary = EmployeeList[idToIncreaseSalary].SalaryIncrease(percentageToIncreaseSalary);

            Console.WriteLine("Updated list of employees: ");

            foreach (var a in EmployeeList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.Id +", "+ a.Name +", "+ a + a.Salary.ToString("F2"));
            }

        }
    }
}

Erro: 

How many employees will be registered?
3
Enter the employee:
Id: 1
Name: AAA AAA
Salary: 2000
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index must be within the bounds of the List. (Parameter 'index')
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Insert(Int32 index, T item)
   at ConsoleApp1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\UDEMY\C# COMPLETO Programação Orientada a Objetos + Projetos\Seção 6\Exercicio\Aula 78 - Listas\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 29

O C:\UDEMY\C# COMPLETO Programação Orientada a Objetos + Projetos\Seção 6\Exercicio\Aula 78 - Listas\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net5.0\ConsoleApp1.exe (processo 22984) foi encerrado com o código -532462766.
Pressione qualquer tecla para fechar esta janela...
```

Comment: Amigo, tu podes colocar o erro em formato texto? fica ruim de ler nessa imagem aí...

Comment: Coloquei o erro no fim do codigo

Comment: Tu excedeste o tamanho da lista. Se a lista tem 5 objetos, tu não podes acessar o elemento 6 que dá esse erro, por exemplo. Recomendo que tu debugue teu código para encontrar o problema.

Comment: Lendo teu código, fiquei com a impressão que tu querias usar u Map em vez de List. Dá uma olhada na documentação para entender as diferenças...

Answer (score -4):

Altere a linha de

```
EmployeeList.Insert(id, Employee);
```

Para

```
EmployeeList.Add(Employee);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu ja tinha feito desse jeito ai, do jeito que postei agr eu tava tentnado pra ja adicionar o elemento na mesma posiçao do index que o id do employee